# ./byfn.sh up error (client version 1.22 is too old Minimum supported API version is 1.24)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am try to run my first network in `hyperledger fabric v 1.3` and I face this problem

> (" ./ byfn.sh -m up
>       client version 1.22 is too old. Minimum supported API version is 1.24, please upgrade your client to a newer version
>       ERROR !!!! Unable to start network
>        ")

Error message:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your Docker version - `docker version`.
Fabric 1.3 requires Docker version 17.06.2-ce or greater.
See https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/prereqs.html